# Why textract asyncronous error with object stored on "folder"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

This is the Error

When i put a file new (object) into a folder in AWS S3, S3 triggers a lambda function and call to start textract asyncronous function. But is does not works. if i put the file on root of S3 bucket everythin works fine.

```
[ERROR] InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartDocumentTextDetection operation: Request has invalid parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 43, in lambda_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 34, in lambda_handler
    'Bucket': bucket
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

This is the code that i tried

```py
    import json
    import urllib.parse
    import boto3

    print('Loading function')

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

        # Get the object from the event and show its content type
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
        textract = boto3.client('textract')

        snstopic = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:PDF_Text_Process_Completed"

        print(key)
        print(type(key))


        try:
            textract.start_document_text_detection(
            JobTag=key + '_Job',
            NotificationChannel={
                'SNSTopicArn': snstopic,
                'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/SNS-new-role'
            },
            DocumentLocation = {
                'S3Object': {
                        'Name': key,
                        'Bucket': bucket
                }
            }
            )

            return 'Triggered PDF Processing for ' + key
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
            raise e
```

Comment: Does your folder or filename contain a space? I notice that it doesn't work if the `Name` of the object contains a space, and probably needs encoding.

Comment: Hi, of course all objects are without spaces.